# Calculate average revenue per user per month

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, average

I have the following dataframe:

```
    Timestamp   userid      Prices_USD
0   2016-12-01  6.270941895 1.08
1   2016-12-01  6.609813209 1.12
2   2016-12-01  6.632094115 9.70
3   2016-12-01  6.655789772 1.08
4   2016-12-01  6.764640751 9.33
... ... ... ...
1183    2017-03-27  6.529604089 1.08
1184    2017-03-27  6.682639674 6.72
1185    2017-03-27  6.773815105 10.0
```

I want to calculate, for each unique userid, their monthly spending.

I've tried the following:

```
sales_per_user.set_index('Timestamp',inplace=True)
sales_per_user.index = pd.to_datetime(sales_per_user.index)
m = sales_per_user.index.month
monthly_avg = sales_per_user.groupby(['userid', m]).Prices_USD.mean().to_frame()
```

But the resulting dataframe is this:

```
userid      Timestamp Prices_USD    
3.43964843  12        10.91
3.885813375 1         10.91
            2         10.91
            12        21.82
```

However, the timestamp column doesn't have the desired outcome. Ideally I would like

```
userid      Timestamp     Prices_USD    
3.43964843  2016-12       10.91
3.885813375 2017-01       10.91
            2017-02       10.91
            2017-12       21.82
```

How do I fix that?

Comment: The userid is a float?

Comment: @DaniMesejo `sales_per_user.dtypes >> Timestamp: object,
userid: object,
Prices_USD: float64`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'])
res = df.groupby([df['userid'], df['Timestamp'].dt.to_period('M')])['Prices_USD'].sum()
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
userid    Timestamp
6.270942  2016-12       1.08
6.529604  2017-03       1.08
6.609813  2016-12       1.12
6.632094  2016-12       9.70
6.655790  2016-12       1.08
6.682640  2017-03       6.72
6.764641  2016-12       9.33
6.773815  2017-03      10.00
Name: Prices_USD, dtype: float64
```

Comment: I get `AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values`.

Comment: Yes, great! Thank you